# Issue in configuring audit/logging with jBPM5

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn

I am trying to configure the audit/logging component of jBPM5 with one of workflow application. I am using jbpm libraries version of 5.5.0.Final for jbpm-human-task-core, jbpm-bpmn2, jbpm-persistence-jpa components. While configuring the same version (5.5.0.Final) for jbpm-audit module is resulting me in build failure exception saying "Could not resolve dependencies for project ". I understand that required dependency for jbpm-audit is not available into central maven repository.

I have verified the central repository and able to find only version 6.0.x. for jbpm-audit module. My queries are

1. Whether it is compatible to use the 6.0.x version of jbpm-audit lib with jbpm 5.5.0.Final other jars?
2. Is there any example/blog or link is available which can point me into right direction?

Greetings,
Mayank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jBPM Version 5 we should use artifact name jbpm-bam as jbpm-audit was introduced in version 6.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% sure that you cannot mix and match version like that in your projects. If you are using jbpm 5.5.0.Final you will need to use all the jars associated with that version in your project.. you can not just using jbpm-audit 6.x along with your jbpm 5.5.0.Final project.

By the way.. if you don't find the jbpm-audit jar in 5.5.0.Final it could be the case that it wasn't provided with that version, which means that you will need to implement something similar if you are planning to stick with that version.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for responding, so you mean there is no way through which I can integrate the audit module with jBPM5?.

Comment: I got the solution. Unknowingly, I was looking into wrong artifact. In jBPM Version 5 we should use artifact name jbpm-bam as jbpm-audit was introduced in version 6.